# image renders even though state visibility is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am planning to render an element or make an element visible only if a button is clicked. But the element gets rendered regardless. Even though the log is saying the state is false

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        number: 0,
        'image1': "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
        visible1: false          
    }
},

add: function(){
    var number = this.state.number;
    number = number+1;
    console.log(number);
    var temp = "visible"
    temp = temp + number
    var s ={};
    s[temp] = true;
    console.log(s);
    this.setState(s); 
},


render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <img  className={"addpicture "+this.state.visible1?"visible":"invisible"} onClick={this.camera} src={this.state.image1} data-cam={1}/>
        <button onClick={this.add}>Click me</button>
        {console.log(this.state.visible1)}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ternary expression `"addpicture "+this.state.visible1?"visible":"invisible"` is evaluating `"addpicture " + this.state.visible`, which due to string coercion returns `"addpicturefalse"`. Since all non-empty strings are truthy, its returning `visible`.

Use parens to wrap your ternary expression in order to isolate the evaluation logic.

`"addpicture "+ (this.state.visible1?"visible":"invisible")`

Comment: Awesome man! How to avoid these kinds of mistakes? How to write safe code in these situations? any advice. I am new to JS

Comment: Just make sure you understand how your expressions are being evaluated. Understand order of evaluation and things like type coercion. For example, what happens with `1 + 'string'` or `+'1'`. It can be tricky!